# Different compiler behavior with C++11

Tags: c++11, g++, complex-numbers, clang++, icc

The following code

```
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <algorithm>

template<class K>
inline void conjVec(int m, K* const in) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<K, double>::value || std::is_same<K, std::complex<double>>::value, "");
    if(!std::is_same<typename std::remove_pointer<K>::type, double>::value)
#ifndef OK
        std::for_each(in, in + m, [](K& z) { z = std::conj(z); });
#else
        std::for_each(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(in), reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(in) + m, [](std::complex<double>& z) { z = std::conj(z); });
#endif
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::vector<double> nums;
    nums.emplace_back(1.0);
    conjVec(nums.size(), nums.data());
    return 0;
}
```

compiles fine on Linux with

1. Debian clang version 3.5.0-9
2. gcc version 4.9.1
3. icpc version 15.0.1

and on Mac OS X with

1. gcc version 4.9.2

but not with

1. clang-600.0.56
2. icpc version 15.0.1

except if the macro `OK` is defined. I don't know which are the faulty compilers, could someone let me know ? Thanks.

PS: here is the error

```
10:48: error: assigning to 'double' from incompatible type 'complex<double>'
        std::for_each(in, in + m, [](K& z) { z = std::conj(z); });
```

Comment: Can you add the compilation errors you get?

Comment: I have updated my first post to include the error. What I don't get is why I get such an error, because to me, the test line 8 can be evaluated during syntax analysis, and so the compilers should know that line 10 is only evaluated when `K = std::complex<double>`, no ?

Comment: The whole function still has to compile. You are trying to use `if` as the (nonexistent) `static if`. Just write two overloads. (The `remove_pointer` is also meaningless. Neither `double` nor `complex<double>` is a pointer.)

Comment: Sorry about the unnecessary `remove_pointer`. Why would you recommend to use two overloads, if I define the macro `OK`, the code compiles and runs fine for both `double` and `complex<double>` on all platform, and I guess the runtime cost of this implementation is not much greater than the with two overloads ?

Comment: Because it is easier to read, and actually shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that on Linux, you're using libstdc++ and glibc, and on MacOS you're using libc++ and whatever CRT MacOS uses.

The MacOS version is correct. (Also, your workaround is completely broken and insanely dangerous.)

Here's what I think happens.

There are multiple overloads of `conj` in the environment. C++98 brings in a single template, which takes a `std::complex<F>` and returns the same type. Because this template needs `F` to be deduced, it doesn't work when calling `conj` with a simple floating point number, so C++11 added overloads of `conj` which take `float`, `double` and `long double`, and return the appropriate `std::complex` instantiation.

Then there's a global function from the C99 library, `::conj`, which takes a C99 `double complex` and returns the same.

libstdc++ doesn't yet provide the new C++11 `conj` overloads, as far as I can see. The C++ version of `conj` isn't called. It appears, however, that somehow `::conj` found its way into the `std` namespace, and gets called. The `double` you pass is implicitly converted to a `double complex` by adding a zero imaginary part. `conj` negates that zero. The result `double complex` is implicitly converted back to a `double` by discarding the imaginary component. (Yes, that's an implicit conversion in C99. No, I don't know what they were thinking.) The result can be assigned to `z`.

libc++ provides the new overloads. The one taking a `double` is chosen. It returns a `std::complex<double>`. This class has no implicit conversion to `double`, so the assignment to `z` gives you an error.

The bottom line is this: your code makes absolutely no sense. A `vector<double>` isn't a `vector<complex<double>>` and shouldn't be treated as one. Calling `conj` on `double` doesn't make sense. Either it doesn't compile, or it's a no-op. (libc++'s `conj(double)` is in fact implemented by simply constructing a `complex<double>` with a zero imaginary part.) And wildly `reinterpret_cast`ing your way around compile errors is horrible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to add that this code is instanciated only with `K = double` or `K = std::complex<double>` (see the updated code above). Looking at the test line 8 of the snippet, the `reinterpret_cast` is only called with `K = std::complex<double>`. Could you comment on why it is "horrible" to `reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>` a `std::complex<double>*` ? I was thinking that this call could be elided by the compiler.

Comment: That wouldn't be horrible, just ugly, and just waiting for some subtle change (maybe switching to `complex<float>`?) to make it horrible again. `reinterpret_cast` is just bad. It would be better to extract the `complex`-specific part of your function into a separate function that has two overloads, one for `double` and one for `complex<double>`. Then you don't have to work around the compiler complaining about invalid operations.

Comment: The OP seems to be missing the fact that code that does not run, still compiles, and must be valid.  A paragraph covering that would improve the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Sebastian Redl's answer explains why your code didn't compile with libc++ but did with libstdc++. `if` is not the `static if` that exists in some languages; even if the code in an `if` branch is 100% dead, it must still be valid code.

In any event, this feels like a massive amount of unnecessary complexity to me. Not everything has to be a template. Especially when your template can only be used with two types, and when used with one of those two it's a no-op.

Compare:

```
template<class K>
inline void conjVec(int m, K* const in) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<K, double>::value || std::is_same<K, std::complex<double>>::value, "");
    if(!std::is_same<K, double>::value)
        std::for_each(reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(in), reinterpret_cast<std::complex<double>*>(in) + m, [](std::complex<double>& z) { z = std::conj(z); });
}
```

with:

```
inline void conjVec(int m, double* const in) {}
inline void conjVec(int m, std::complex<double>* const in) {
    std::for_each(in, in + m, [](std::complex<double>& z) { z = std::conj(z); });
}
```

I know which one I would prefer.